# laravel using a different php version

Tags: php, laravel

I've a lamp stack installed on my localhost. I just installed everything I needed via the command line, but I'm not very knowledgable about how the server works.

So when I just start a very simple php project from scratch, simply make a folder in the root directory and create an index.php with phpinfo() at the top, I find that I'm running php 7.3.

Then when I created another folder with a laravel installation inside (I didn't set up, just copied files and made the required changes - it works fine - note I'm just messing about with laravel, no expert!). If I stick a phpinfo() at the top of a file in the laravel project, it says I'm on php7.4!

How is it possible that the two projects, on the same server  which are running different php versions?

Comment: You can easily have multiple versions of PHP. How do you launch these 2 site

Comment: Don't believe or trust `phpinfo()`. Use the command `“php –version”` or `“php -v”` to get the version of PHP installed on your system. Read [this question](https://superuser.com/a/971895/1143120) you will find more

Comment: That will show the version of PHP that you have setup for the CLI and not necessarily the one used by Apache @sta And WHY would you not trust `phpinfo()` .... asking for a friend :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added  more on my comment for clarification

Comment: @sta Thanks, but that is saying what I said and nothing about not trusting `phpinfo()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly - sorry was reading the link from sta. The simple site, I just go to localhost/simple_project. For the laravel one I have to use php artisan serve from the commandline inside the laravel folder. Then visit http://127.0.0.1:8000. Is there a way to make php artisan serve use a different php version from just visiting localhost?

Comment: And also, if I install something like sudo apt install php7.4-zip and then sudo apt install php7.3-zip restart apache, will that affect both versions of php?

Comment: There are two php version installed in your system. Your apache use one and `php artisan serve` uses the system's php version only.

Comment: There is the reason, I think. Your Web Server `localhost/.....` is using one version of php, but when you do use `php artisan serve` the `php` bit is using the PHP CLI and running the builtin server. So your CLI is using 7.4 and the web server is configured to use 7,3

Comment: Thank you so much :-) I understand now